# Is there a need to delete a large variable in python immediately after its use?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

If I create a list that’s 1 GB, print it to screen, then delete it, would it also be deleted from memory?  Would this deletion essentially be like deallocating memory such as free() in C.

If a variable is very large should I delete it immediately after use or should I let Python's garbage collector handle it ?

```
# E.g. creating and deleting a large list

largeList = ['data', 'etc', 'etc'] # Continues to 1 GB
print largeList
largeList = []   # Or would it need to be:  del largeList [:]
```

Comment: `largeList = [] ` would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, **you shouldn't worry about memory management in a garbage collected language**. That means actions such as deleting variables (in python), or calling the garbage collector (GC) manually.

You should trust the GC to do its job properly  - most of the time, **micromanaging memory will lead to adverse results**, as the GC has a lot more information and statistics about what memory is used and needed than you. Also, **garbage collection is a expensive process** (CPU-wise), so there's a good chance you'd be calling it too often/in a bad moment.

What happens in your example is that, as soon as ỳou `largeList = []`, the memory content previously referenced will be GC'd as soon as its convenient, or the memory is needed.

You can check this using a interpreter and a memory monitor:

```
#5 MiB used
>>> l1=[0]*1024*1024*32
#261 MiB used
>>> l2=[0]*1024*1024*32
#525 MiB used
>>> l1=[0]*1024*1024*32
# 525 MiB used
```

There are *very rare* cases where you *do* need to manage memory manually, and you turn off garbage collection. Of course, that can lead to memory leak bugs [such as this one](http://bugs.python.org/issue7943). It's worth mentioning that the modern python GC can handle circular references properly.

Answer (score 0):

Using "die" ---> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace. It releases memory for sure but not all the memory is released.

NOTE: When a process frees some memory from HEAP, it releases back to the OS only after the process dies.

So, better leave it for the Garbage Collector.

Comment: Whether memory is returned to the OS is platform and implementation dependent.